# vue2 highlight updated rows

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking for a way to highlight updated rows to a user in vue2. I am currently generating the table using v-for:

```
<table class="table temptable">
      <tbody v-if="this.tempItems">
      <tr>
          <th>SKU</th>
          <th>QTY</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="item in this.tempItems" :class="{ rowFlash: item.rowUpdated }">
      <td data-title="SKU">@{{ item.sku }}</td>
      <td data-title="QTY">@{{ item.qty }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried transition, transition group. The closest I have got is using a `:class="{ rowFlash: item.rowUpdated }"` to the `<tr>` but I have not found a way to get the final result.

I am ultimately looking for the row to be highlighted (background-color:red) on either insert OR update and then fade away after a few seconds back to white.

**EDIT**

My JS code is as follows:

```
this.vm.tempItems[response.data.sku].qty += 1;
```

This is initiated via a scanner API. So when the scan fires, it sends the code off to a script and brings back the product SKU. The vue instance is only being ran on this single page of my site so I am not using a vue template at the moment. All of this JS runs in the footer script of the page.

**EDIT 2**

I have got something working but I do not think this is a great solution!

JS

```
this.vm.tempItems[response.data.sku].rowUpdated = false;
setTimeout(function(){ this.vm.tempItems[response.data.sku].rowUpdated = true; }, 50);
```

CSS

```
.rowRed{
    background: #ee815b;
}

.rowFade {
    background: white !important;
    transition: 1.5s !important;
}
```

By changing the class of the row using `:class="{ rowFlash: item.rowUpdated }"` and then immediately changing it back, it gives me the red highlight fade out effect. It feels messy though and I do not like the idea of having a setTimeout in there. However without the timeout I am not sure how to get the vue attribute to change back to false after it has been set to true?

Comment: are you sure about `rowUpdated` property, that it gets updated?

Comment: Yes it gets updated ok. I can actually get the row to change to red but I am not sure how to a) flash it and b) clear all the other rowUpdated properties on the other rows, as they are now all set to true.

Comment: template looks good(you can remove `this` word in template by the way), but i think question needs some js code and css for better understanding your problem

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I think the right approach for you is to use a `<transition-group>`

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that you didn't bind `:key` on each element. Try again with the transition group and add `v-bind:key="item.id"` Let me know if it works.

Comment: I did try <transition-group> actually but I understand this only works for new/inserted rows. Not updated rows. I am looking to put this effect on both new and updated rows. I have added some js into the above question.

Comment: Can't do the troubleshooting without MCV codes. but you can check this [simple sample](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/116966/), it may help you.

Comment: @Sphinx - thanks that does help. I have got that bit working in my code and can now get the rows to highlight when they update... however as the vue attribute is now set to true and I am not sure how to clear it. I expect there is a way to fade out the css highlight with a transition? However for the next time the row updates I need it to be set to false before true again. Any ideas?

Comment: @AdamLambert Not sure what is your goal. probably [one watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) can help you. or you can post another quesiton then provide MCV codes.